# getting path error (404) in .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using `.htaccess` file for redirecting page. I have tried both paths, absolute and relative, but in both the cases I am getting error: `URL not found (404)`.

Please guide me proper way to mention path in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /abc.php?tag=$1
```

Comment: Is `abc.php` in the root of your server?

Comment: yes it is in the root folder of local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `RewriteBase /`.

Try adding that just before your `RewriteRule`, i.e:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Also try removing the slash before `abc`:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ abc.php?tag=$1
```

---

One good way to debug the URL rewriting, is to switch on the rewrite logging.

In Apache 2.2:

```
RewriteLog file-path.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

The syntax is different for Apache 2.4. [Read more here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog).

Comment: yes sir I have tried that also but it is not even creating error log files.It is not able to recognize any of the path.   I am working on ubuntu and I have saved my files at var/www folder on my local machine.